# karate does not return all variables that were defined (using def) in the 'called' feature

Tags: karate, karate-call-single

I have the following file karate-config-test.js

```
 function fn() {    
  var env = karate.env; // get system property 'karate.env'
  var baseUrl = "http://localhost:5000"
  var config = {
    env: env,
    baseUrl: baseUrl
  };

  //open connection to message broker (mqtt, amqp)
  var async_message = karate.callSingle('classpath:com/connect/apitests/commons/async_message/async_message.feature', config);
  config.mqtt = async_message.mqtt
  config.amqp = async_message.amqp
 
  return config;
}
```

And the following feature async_message.feature

```
@ignore

Feature: utility that instance async message broker
Background:
 
  * url baseUrl 

Scenario: Set instance of a class AmqpUtils And MqttUtils
    * def amqp = 'pippo'
   
Scenario: Set instance of a class MqttUtils
    * def mqtt = 'pluto'
```

when i check the value of the variable **async_message i see the variables of one scenario but not both**, for example I saw only mqtt.
Why is this happening?
In karate documentation I read

- All variables that were defined (using def) in the 'called' script would be returned as 'keys' within a JSON-like object.

Comment: sorry, this is too much to read and digest. also the use of `callSingle()` has effects that may be responsible. follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas I update the desciption. my question is simple: when in the called feature have more than one scenario, the caller feature does not see all variables from the called feature

Comment: well yes, because it is designed to only call one scenario. the last scenario called is what you see in the return. you are welcome to submit a PR to improve the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate is designed so that when you do a `call` of any kind, the last `Scenario` is what is considered for returning variables.

In other words, the best practice is to call one `Scenario` at a time. You can use tags to "isolate" scenarios if you don't like splitting scenarios into different files.